# Sorting by expression in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have zones, and tickets sold within those zones....I use the following query to get the number of tickets sold per zone, and I need to sort so that the available zones (where thecount < capacity) are at the top of the sortorder:

```
SELECT z.name, z.capacity,count(t.ticketid) as thecount  
FROM tickets t JOIN zones z ON z.zoneid=t.zoneid 
GROUP BY z.name ORDER BY z.sortorder
```

returns:

+--------+----------+----------+
  name            cap            thecount
+--------+----------+----------+
  Zone1  |     100          |    100
  Zone2  |     300        |   300
  Zone3  |     250        |    101
  Zone4  |     600          |    522
  Zone5  |     160          |    160
+--------+----------+----------+

I need the sort to be in the following order:
Zone3
Zone4
Zone1
Zone2
Zone5

I'm not sure how to use an expression or something else to achieve this---any helpful hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, capacity - thecount AS availableSeats
FROM (
    SELECT z.name, z.capacity,count(t.ticketid) as thecount  
    FROM tickets t JOIN zones z ON z.zoneid=t.zoneid 
    GROUP BY z.name
) t
ORDER BY availableSeats, name
```

I think you might also need to group by `z.name, z.capacity`.

Comment: Thanks, this works with a little modification---I've posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT z.name, z.capacity,count(t.ticketid) as thecount   
FROM tickets t JOIN zones z ON z.zoneid=t.zoneid  
GROUP BY z.name  
order by case when thecount < c.capacity
              then thecount
              else c.capacity
         end
```

Comment: Sorry, i get a "Reference 'thecount' not supported (reference to group function)" on this one   --  and I changed your c.capacity to z.capacity)

Answer (score 0):

So, based on GWilliams00 answer I ended up with :

```
SELECT *, capacity < thecount AS availableSeats
FROM (
   SELECT z.name, z.capacity,count(t.ticketid) as thecount  
   FROM gt_tickets t JOIN gt_zones z ON z.zoneid=t.zoneid  
   GROUP BY z.name

) t
ORDER BY availableSeats,sortorder
```

The 'capacity < thecount' evaluates to a boolean, so this can be used to sort the available zones , then sortorder keeps them in the right name order after that.