# mysql using select with an arithmetic expression

Tags: mysql, sorting, arithmetic-expressions

I am trying to use select in combination with an arithmetic expression

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY (`column1` / max(`column1`)* `column2`);
```

The problem is that it return a single row rather than all the rows sorted base on the expression.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just order by column1.  Dividing by a constant doesn't change the order.

EDIT: Add your expression as another field in the select.  E.g.,

```
SELECT *, x+y as z ORDER BY z
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10762333/2877364 for a full example of a similar situation.

Comment: this was just an example I would like to know how to use a function in arithmetic expression. I have edited the question